Minimal model for $A_\infty$-categories
Is there a reference for existence and construction of the minimal model of an $A_\infty$-category? Most references I found ultimately refer to Lefèvre-Hasegawa's thesis but there doesn't seem to be a precise statement for categories, just algebras. I would appreciate statements for the strictly unital case.

Can't you build an algebra from the category and work with that?

@Pedro If you could do that, then all schemes in your world are affine, and this fact does not really agree with reality.

Have you checked Chapter 1 of Seidel's Fukaya categories and Picard-Lefschetz theory?
